# How to prevent sceneFunc() from clearing the context each time?

Tags: ios, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

In [KonvaJS](https://konvajs.github.io/) defining `sceneFunc()` for any `Shape` will result in calling it each time `draw()` is called,

1. `Shape.draw()`
2. `layer.draw()`
3. `stage.draw()`

The question is: How to prevent `sceneFunc()` from clearing the context and persist the past drawings on the previous call of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearBeforeDraw` property:

```
var layer = new Konva.Layer({clearBeforeDraw: false});
```

From docs:

> set this property to false if you don't want to clear the canvas
>   before each layer draw. The default value is true.